# What is the formula for series like $-a1, -a2, +a3, +a4, -a5, -a6...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just wonder how to come up with the "formula" for any series like:

$-a1, -a2, +a3, +a4, -a5, -a6...$

or maybe:
$-, -, -, +, +, +$

or any of these variations with sequences of same signs but alternating.

Sorry for the poorly formulated question.

Comment: What do you mean?  You can define the terms of your sequence however you like.

Comment: You could start by $(-1)^{\text{floor(x/n)}}$ where $n$ is some integer, 3 or 4 or whatever you like.

Comment: Just put some numbers where your letters are.

Comment: @lulu, thank you for the response. That's what I meant actually. How to define sequences like those. I will edit my question.

Comment: I think the confusion is in what do you mean by "define". Other comments are trying to tell you that you've already defined these sequences as long as you're clear in the pattern, so it's not clear what you're looking for. Maybe a closed expression in terms of the original $a_i$?

Comment: I presume what the OP means is: find a closed-form formula that produces the *signs* of the terms, given the index.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sequence $-1, -1, +1, +1, -1, -1, ...$ you can put
$$s(n) = \begin{cases} -1,\textit{if }\ n = 4k \textit{ or }\ 4k + 1\\
+1,\textit{if  }\ n = 4k + 2 \textit{ or }\ 4k + 3,\end{cases}$$
or you can define it inductively:
$$s(0) = s(1) = -1,\\
s(n) = \begin{cases} -s(n-1),\textit{if }\ s(n-1) = s(n-2)\\
\phantom{-}s(n-1),\textit{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean, maybe something like

$$
\sum_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+3)}.
$$

Indeed

$$
\sum_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+3)}=\sum_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)=\sum_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3n+4}+\frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{1}{3n+5}+\frac{1}{3n+3}-\frac{1}{3n+6}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{3}\sum_0^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}-\frac{1}{3n+4}-\frac{1}{3n+5}-\frac{1}{3n+6}\right)=\frac{1}{3} \sum_0^{+\infty} (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\rfloor} \frac{1}{3n+6\{\frac{n}{6}\}+1}
$$
(where $\{\frac{n}{6}\}$ is the fractional part of $\frac{n}{6}$) which is a telescoping series (take $a_n=\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}$) that converges to $\frac{1}{3}a_0=\frac{11}{18}$. Maybe from this example you can obtain something similar to what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try to understand.